# What can i test on these types of methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

Sorry for this orrible title, i did my best.
Maybe someone with more imagination can help me and this title.

I am a newbie in Unit Testing and I am a bit lost. I am reading "The Art of Unit Tesing" anyway.

I am using Entity Framework 6 for a WebApi application.
In this applicantion i use this pattern:

Api calls Service that calls Repository that return data to service that return data to API.

So, I have a tons of this methods:

API:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserById(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        return Ok(await userService.GetById(id));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class UserService
{
    private IUserRepository userRepo;
    public IUserRepository userRepo { get => userRepo; set => userRepo = value }

    public async Task<AspNetUser> GetById(Guid id)
    {
        if(id == Guid.Empty() || id == null)
            return null;

        return await Task.Run(() => userRepo.GetById(id));
    }
}
```

Repo:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    Task<AspNetUser> GetById(Guid id);
}

public class UserRepository: IUserRepository
{

    public async Task<AspNetUser> GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

What can be faulty here? what can go wrong? What i should test?

Comment: Begin to think "test at the interface level" here perhaps? i.e. the `GetById(Guid id)` is there.

Comment: Delete your implementation to start off with and think what behavior do I want this class to encapsulate.

Comment: I updated my post with the correct example. I messed up the code in the last one.
What do you meen with "test at the interface level"? @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: @KevinSmith i don't get this part: "think what behavior do i want this class to encapsulate"

Comment: i.e. don't test each getter and setter for example if it works at the interface level it seems those are/would be working.  You CAN test those but not sure the level of value it adds.

Comment: @ImFlash what output you want from the given inputs

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the test will use dependency injection to "inject" the repository so i can test the service as well.

Comment: @KevinSmith If the id is null, return null. If the id exist so give me the user, if the id don't exist give me null. Do you meen this?

Comment: @ImFlash yeah, that's the tests that you should write, I find breaking them down in to GWTs (Given When Thens) helps, Given a user with an ID exists, When getting user by ID, Then the user is returned

Comment: @KevinSmith Actually must i test the user given with THAT id is the correct User in DB or i only need to test that a `new AspNetUser()` is returned?

Comment: Test that the AspNetUser is returned, If you're just unit testing then try to isolate each "unit" aka class

Comment: Search on "How to Unit Test a Repository Implementation" as well to get more generic viewpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of unit testing is to test each module (*usually equates to a method*) of code in isolation. This is only possible with loose coupling. In your existing code you do not use DI (dependency injection) and you instantiate service / repository classes in your methods. This makes testing this code in isolation difficult if not almost impossible. Writing unit tests often reveals design/code flaws like these. Refactor your code as follows:

---

1. Use interfaces, you did it on your repository but not on your service but that is actually the best place to use an interface.
2. Use dependency injection. This will make testing much easier.
3. Why are you using a repository pattern around EF? EF's DbSet is a generic implementation of a repository pattern and DbContext is an implementation of Unit of Work. I strongly recommend not trying to re-encapsolate these in your own half baked abstractions, you are only going to end up making it more difficult for your self to use your own constructs.
4. That is not the correct way to use async/await. Call through to an async method and if non exists then do not create an async method to begin with (*this does not apply to cases where you want to use TPL*). In your case you should call through to `FirstOrDefaultAsync` (or possible `SingleOrDefaultAsync`);
5. Name your async methods with the suffix `Async`, this is considered proper convention.

**UserController.cs**

```
private readonly IUserService userService;
public UserController(IUserService userService){
  this.userService = userService;
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserById(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(await userService.GetByIdAsync(id));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

**UserService.cs**

```
public interface IUserService{
  Task<AspNetUser> GetByIdAsync(Guid id);
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    // you can leave MyDbContext unsealed or you can use an interface on this as well depending on your needs
    private readonly MyDbContext dbContext;
    public UserService(MyDbContext dbContext) {
      this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Task<AspNetUser> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        if(id == Guid.Empty())
            return Task.FromResult(null as AspNetUser);
        return dbContext.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(user => user.Id == id);
    }
}
```

---

Having done this now you can unit test your code. You can use a popular fake/mock/substitute framework and do the following:

1. Create a test for your api's `GetUserById` by creating a mock `IUserService` instance with custom behavior on `GetByIdAsync`
2. Create a test for the `UserService::GetByIdAsync` method by creating a mock of `MyDbContext`, you can supply a collection of `AspNetUser` instances and test which one is returned when calling the method or even test the expression that the DbSet is called with.

As far as what you should test depends on possible inputs and the corresponding expected results. For example : What happens when you pass in an empty GUID into GetByIdAsync? What does the API do when a null result is returned in the Task? etc.

Comment: Nice. I will do it for sure. In point 4 i have some trouble with EF and Async/await with (i think) my visual studio because when i use FirstOrDefaultAsync or ListAsync the task still in "Waiting for activation". I didn't found a solution yet.
Point 3: I use a Repository because in there i have important methods such as "Remove" or "Update" that mark that entity with "Deleted" or "Modified" state.
I use DI on the property. I don't like to specify everytime the service and i don't like 2 constructor.

Comment: Example 2: at least but not least, why you use `dbContext.AspNetUsers` and not  `dbSet.Set<AspNetUser>()`?

Comment: @ImFlash - you can create a property of type `DbSet<AspNetUser>` on the `DbContext` type or you can use the generic `Set<AspNetUser>` on the generic `DbContext`, the choice is yours and there is not right answer on that.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I will use more interfaces and i will put "Async" in my async methods.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, this is likely NOT the "best" answer here and I am up voting others.

As this is getting a bit "long" for comments so I am posting as an answer with the "what" more so than the "how" here as Igor has done - good stuff there!

This will be somewhat generic in that regard.

Test what I call the "happy path" i.e. a valid GUID (in your instance) gets something valid.

Perhaps something valid from a string:

`Guid g = new Guid("11223344-5566-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00");`

Test something invalid (not present for example)

`Guid g = new Guid(someinvalidthingthatparses);`

New:

`Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();`

all 0's i.e. `Guid.Empty`

Test uninitiated values

In a perfect world, some of these should not get to the method being tested but what if they do?  How does it react?

To extrapolate further, I digress but if you are testing something for example that passes an integer as `Int32` that might only accept positive values test the boundaries i.e. 0, 1, -1, `Int32.MaxValue`, `Int32.MinValue` `Int32.MaxValue - 1` `Int32.MinValue + 1`, begin to think (as you appear to be doing) how to break it.  IF you run into a failure condition later, add a unit test for that for example.  If you are passing something that will be in a repo somewhere, also consider the limits of that - for example date min/max differs in sql vs C# and by date vs DateTime etc.  BeginDate/EndDate - is it inclusive or not etc.

Now each of those "FAILURE" points should do something, how is this handled by the callers/API code?  How does it respond if an error is thrown?

Comment: My Api read that null as "Men, this User doesn't exist. Return this to the client as an error and handle it client side". Thank you for your efforts! I like this "Happy path".